# VB.NET Find element, execute onclick and manage it on new tab in webbrowser

Tags: vb.net

thanks for reading, I'm stuck trying to find an element of a webbrowser document, it doesn't have any ID, neither a classname, it just has an onclick attribute and an href attribute that is "#". What I need to do is to find such element and execute the "onclick" attribute it has, also I need to manage it because usually it opens in a new window. Thanks.

Update #1
My code so far:

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.All
        If element.GetAttribute("href").ToString.Contains("#") Then
            element.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
```

Update #2:
The code of the first update still not working, but now I managed to open the new window in a new form.

```
 ' This will be triggered only when link tries to open in new window. 
    ' That means active element in web document will always be a Link.

    Dim myElement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement
    Dim target As String = myElement.GetAttribute("href")

    Dim newInstance As New Form1
    newInstance.Show()
    newInstance.WebBrowser1.Navigate(target)

    'cancel opening IE window
    e.Cancel = True
```

Comment: So have you actually tried to write some code? I'l suggest you to start with that, and if you have a specific quesiton related to code problems, we will be glad to help.

Comment: I have already being coding for about a week and I'm unable to nail it. I have updated the question and included my poor code.